# Making API call using retrofit 2 in android

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to make an API call using retrofit 2 in android for a given link. I am very new to making API calls.

Can someone help me with, from where should I start?

Comment: There are plenty of examples you will find over google. Along with source code so first find there and if you face any issue then write here.

Answer (score 1):

Check out an article like this, https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html.

Overall, Retrofit is very straight forward once you get the hang of it.

All you really need to do is create an `interface` for your API call and create a model for the response.

```
public interface GerritAPI {

    @GET("changes/")
    Call<List<Change>> loadChanges(@Query("q") String status);
}
```

And then call the API using the `Retrofit` client.

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    GerritAPI gerritAPI = retrofit.create(GerritAPI.class);

    Call<List<Change>> call = gerritAPI.loadChanges("status:open");
    call.enqueue(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface like this:

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("chat")
    Call<SendMSGResponse> sendMsg(
            @Header("Authorization") String token,
            @Field("sender_id") String userId     
    ); 
}
```

Now Create Retrofit connection class:

```
 public class Util {

    public static String BASE_URL = "https://example.com/api/";

    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static ApiInterface getApiInterface() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }
}
```

Call this method in Activity class:

```
    Util.getApiInterface().sendChat("token","33")
                .enqueue(new Callback<SendMSGResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<SendMSGResponse> call, Response<SendMSGResponse> response) {
                        Log.d("TAG","Success :-"+response.body().getMessage());
                        if (response.body() != null){
                            Log.d("TAG","Success :-"+response.body().getData().getMessage());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<SendMSGResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("TAG","Success :-"+t.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```